# How to redirect error output to both stdout and to stderr?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm putting together a complex pipeline, where I want to include stderr in the program output for recordkeeping purposes but I also want errors to remain on stderr so I can spot problems.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12517519/699305) that asks how to direct stdout+stderr to a file and still get stderr on the terminal; it's close, but I don't want to redirect stdout to a file yet: The program's output will be consumed by other scripts, so I'd like it to remain on stdout (and same for stderr). So, to summarize:

- Script produces output in fd 1, errors in fd 2.
- I want the calling program to rearrange things so that output+errors appear in fd 1, errors in fd 2.
- Also, errors should be interleaved with output (as much as their own buffering allows), not saved and added at the end.

Due-diligence notes: Capturing stderr is easy enough with `2>&1`. Saving and viewing stdout is easy enough by piping through `tee`. I also know how to divert stdout to a file and direct stderr through a pipe: `command 2>&1 1>fileA | tee fileB.` But how do I duplicate stderr and put stdout back in fd 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As test to generate both stdout and stderr, let's use the following:

```
{ echo out; echo err >&2; }
```

The following code demonstrates how both stdout and stderr can be sent to the next step in the pipeline while also sending stderr to the terminal:

```
$ { echo out; echo err >&2; } 2> >(tee /dev/stderr) | cat >f
err
$ cat f
out
err
```

#### How it works

- `2>`

  This redirects stderr to the (pseudo) file which follows.
- `>(tee /dev/stderr)`

  This is *process substitution* and its acts as a pseudo-file that receives input from stderr.  Any input it receives is sent to the `tee` command which sends it both to stderr and to stdout.

Comment: Right, process substitution! That's how to direct non-stdout to a pipe... But what's the point of `>&1` in the `tee` subprocess? Looks like it just makes stdout into a copy of stdout.

Comment: Also, sending errors to /dev/tty will probably work, but it's not what I was hoping for-- if I ever need to capture "standard error" into a file, I'll have my hands full of the script's guts.

Comment: Looks like `2> >(tee /dev/stderr)` does exactly what I needed, though. Thanks!

Comment: @alexis Good suggestion!  I updated the answer to go to `/dev/stderr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using `x=$(some_function | tee /dev/stderr)` and testing success using `PIPESTATUS` but that doesn't work. But with your solution it works.